# Modificar el tamaño y centrar imagen al hacer drag-and-drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

Estoy haciendo drag de una imagen y soltarla en un `div`. Para ello uso el `"helper:clone"` para clonarla. Lo que necesito es que al soltarla se modifique el tamaño de la imagen y quede centrada en el `div`.

¿Alguien sabe cómo podría hacerlo?

Ejemplo:

Quiero poner la imagen dentro del 'droppable31', ajustando la imagen al tamaño del 'droppable31'

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var x = null;

  //Make element draggable
  $(".drag").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    cursor: 'move',
    tolerance: 'pointer',
  });

  $("#droppable31").droppable({

    drop: function(e, ui) {

      if ($(ui.draggable)[0].id != "") {
        x = ui.helper.clone();
        ui.helper.remove();
        x.draggable({
          helper: 'original',
          containment: '#droppable31',
          tolerance: 'pointer',
        });
        x.appendTo('#droppable31');
        /*x.effect("size", { to: {width: '100',height: '100'} }, 1000);
        x.animate({'marginTop' : "+=10px"},{'marginLeft' : "+=10px"});*/
      }

    }
  });

});
```

```css
.col {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#col1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#droppable3 {
  margin-left: 350px;
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#droppable31 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="row">
      <div class="col" id="col1">
        <div id="drag1" class="drag"><img src="https://www.consulti.es/imagenes/lamp.png" width="200" height="100" alt="Foto"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="row">
      <div class="col" id="droppable3">
        <div class="col" id="droppable31"> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>
```

Comment: Hola Cris, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español. Por favor, edita la pregunta para crear un [mcve] y que podamos ver/reproducir el problema. Saludos.

Comment: En qué fallas y qué has intentado para lograr lo que necesitas ?

Comment: Ya he añadido un ejemplo y explicación de lo que necesito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que al clonar el objeto `helper` lo clonas con todos los atributos que jQuery UI ha añadido.

De la misma forma cuando utilizas `effect` para cambiar el tamaño de la imagen, este método añade atributos de márgenes y posicionamiento que hacen que luego el elemento no se comporte como esperas.

Yo utilizaría el objeto original (`ui.draggable`) para hacer la copia a insertar. Incluso podrías coger únicamente la imagen contenida en lugar del elemento `div`.

Después puedes ajustar y centrar la imagen estableciendo su ancho a un porcentaje del contenedor y los márgenes a un valor adecuado. Para mantener la relación de aspecto de la imagen puedes establecer la altura a `auto`.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var x = null;

  //Make element draggable
  $(".drag").draggable({
      helper: 'clone',
      cursor: 'move',
      tolerance: 'pointer', 
  });

   $("#droppable31").droppable({
      drop: function (e, ui) {
        var x = ui.draggable.find('img').clone();
        $(this).append(x);
        x.css('height', 'auto');
        x.animate({width: '90%', margin: '5%', display: 'block'}, 1000);
      }
    });

});
```

```css
.col{
  float:left;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#col1{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid black;
}

#droppable3{
  margin-left:350px;
  width:200px;
  min-height :300px;
  border:1px solid black;
}

#droppable31{
  width:100px;
  height :100px;
  border:1px solid black;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
            <div id="row">
                    <div class = "col" id="col1">
                             <div id="drag1" class="drag"><img src="https://www.consulti.es/imagenes/lamp.png" width="200" height="100" alt="Foto"></div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div id="row">
                <div class="col" id ="droppable3">
                     <div class="col" id ="droppable31"> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, es lo que necesitaba.

Comment: @CrisPonsGarriga si esta respuesta resolvió el problema, por favor, márcala como aceptada pulsando en la marca que se encuentra en la parte superior izquierda de la respuesta. Gracias!